# Theming user-edit form drupal 6

Tags: theming, users

After installing tons of modules like guestbook, subscriptions etc. It also added tons of settings on `user/$uid/edit` page. How can I disable or rearrange them?

I guess [`theme_fieldset()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/theme_fieldset/6) would help me, but I have no idea how to use it correctly. And where to `print_r($form)` and in which template?

Answer (score 3):

[devel themer](http://drupal.org/project/devel_themer) will help you understand what you can over ride and what variables are available.

[hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_form_alter/6) can be used to trim fields that you don't want and to re order the form, put things into groups etc.

Answer (score 1):

hook_form_alter

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id)
        case 'user-profile-form':
        // Change $form array to alter form components
        break;
```

Comment: thanks, in my case its node-form id. And how can i see a fieldset's id?

Comment: You will have to print_r($form) for its structure and to decide for your desired field-set to hide by unset($form['myfieldset'])

Comment: can you post an example for "language fieldset" on user-edit page, please?

I've created mymodule.module and pasted your code above, what to write in // Change $form array to alter form components? :)

Comment: (1) `book_form_alter` should be `mymodule_form_alter`

Comment: thanks, but i've already knew that. I meant what to write inside
function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id){
    switch($form_id)
        case 'user-profile-form':
        // What to write here?
        break;

Comment: unset($form['name_of_fieldset'], $form['name_of_other_fieldset']);

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CASE, expecting ':' or '{' in /home/u3510/domains/ruh.kz/sites/all/modules/tf/tf.module on line 4

Comment: case 'user-profile-form': - there's error